# WPF listview selection problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview (in extended selection mode and synchronized with the current item) and a textbox. The textbox allows the user to input search criteria. On the TextChanged event of the listbox I match the search criteria to the names of listviewitems in the listview and set the selectedindex accordingly. This is to both highlight it and provide an easy selection point to select further points from. See the code below:

```
    void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                string text = textBox.Text;
                if (text != string.Empty)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listViewPerson.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Person person = (Person)listViewPerson.Items[i];
                        if (person != null)
                        {
                            if (person .Name.StartsWith(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                listViewPerson.SelectedIndex = i;
                                listViewPerson.ScrollIntoView(routePoint);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    listViewPerson.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Caught)
        {
            Log.AddExceptionEntry(this, "Could not search ", Caught, Log.Target.All,
                Log.EntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

The searching and selection works just fine. On the first attempt the user can select a second point (the first is already selected by the search) and multi-select from the first without a problem.

However 2nd time round the listview continues to 'remember' the first selected point from the first search (which was originally set by the search routine), therefore causing the selection to start from the wrong place (even though the selectedindex is correctly set to the new item in the listview).

However, a mouse click on the selectedindex then causes the selection point to be reset correcty. It seems like selectedindex works differently in code compared to using manual clicks.

I've tried using listViewTrainServiceHelperPattern.SelectedItems.Clear(), SelectedValue(object) instead of SelectedIndex, but all to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this and how to work around it?

Comment: I've read through a few times, but am still a bit confused about some missing pieces of info. What does selecting a second 'point' mean, and what action or event starts the '2nd time round the listview'. If you have multiple items selected, the 'selectedindex' will return the first selected index, not the most recently selected index. However, from your question, I can't tell what happens between the first time your search engine runs and the '2nd time round'. Do all items get cleared, do you perform custom logic...?

Comment: What is `routePoint`?  It seems this might live across invocations of this event.  Also, this code doesn't look very "MVVM" to me, because it has view logic in code-behind rather than in the view model.  If you were having problems handling `TextChanged` in real time with MVVM, try this in your binding: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to a Wpf treeview bug where if you set the IsSelected on an item through a binding, the logical focus remains with the previously selected item. Try getting a handle to the newly selected ListViewItem using ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newlySelectedItem) and then call focus() on it. I'd be really interested to hear if this works for you.